# Is there any way to restrict Codeigniter or Laravel script to only one computer per client?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, security

I am setting up source of codeigniter/laravel on client machine using xampp and want to prevent reuse/redistribution of code by client. I tried to implement this concept using  obfuscator but it won't work.
also I search many ways to implement this concept, like:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}`enter code here`
?>
```

but it won't work.

Comment: Just curious is it a software your client own but you have developed for him/her or its a service/product of yours which your client is going to user as a service?

Comment: you can't, if they read your code, they can re-use it.

Comment: How about putting it on a server? Is the requirement to instal it on the client's machine mendatory?

Comment: client don't want online, he want on localhost only

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to explore this option -

https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

"PHP Desktop works the same way. The difference is that PHP Desktop does not require any particular installation; it is an all-in-one portable set of all these local servers have and it does all you can do with WampServer or Xamp and others in the same family."

It does support Laravel and CodeIgniter. Here's the full list of frameworks being supported - https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/PHP-frameworks-support

You can read this article to help you start here at https://phpocean.com/tutorials/design-and-illustration/create-your-first-desktop-application-with-php-and-php-desktop/4

Comment: but here user can edit,delete or copy that source code files.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't do that. if you install your source code on their local network they have full access to it, unless you restrict their access to the local server.